# Trying to clear error box when focus is on textbox

Tags: jquery

I have an error `<div>` I would like to clear text when the user brings focus back into the textbox.

The issue is when I set focus back the function doesn't fire?

```
$(".mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution_text").focus(function () {

    $("#mod_EasyTabCalculator_display_error_msg").text("");

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution">
    <p id="mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_price_text">Enter your
        <br />upfront contribution</p>
    <div id="mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_text_box">
        <input class="go" id="mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_dollar_sign">
        <input type="text" value="" class="mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution_text" name="down" id="mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution_text" placeholder="Amount*" maxlength="6" size="6" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <input id="mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution_button" type="button" class="btn" value="Calculate Payment" onclick="calculatePayment()" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: can we see your html mark up as well?

Comment: this does work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your jquery in document ready like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution_text").focus(function () {
        alert("focus in!");
        $("#mod_EasyTabCalculator_display_error_msg").text("");

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks you that is exactly what it was I had it down in my javascript not in the document ready fuction

Answer (score 0):

if `mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution_text` is your input id you need to get it with `#`

```
 $("#mod_EasyTabCalculator_device_contribution_text").focus(function () {

    $("#mod_EasyTabCalculator_display_error_msg").text("");

});
```

Comment: It is a class name selector.